# How to send multiple FormData objects to server using AJAX and access those objects on the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am trying to develop a page where teachers can go and create quizzes for their students. To meet this end, there are two forms on the page. One form is for creating the actual quiz and the other is for creating the questions that go on the quiz.

Everytime the teacher adds a question to the quiz, a JS function is called which saves the question data locally in a FormData object, which is then placed into an array of questions. Keep in mind that one of the inputs on the question form is a file input.

When the teacher finally submits the quiz, I use an AJAX call that sends two items to the server: a FormData object containing the quiz data and an array of FormData objects containing the information about the questions on the quiz.

My question is: how do I access these different objects on the server? I am using CakePHP so my initial thought was `$this->request->data["quiz"]` and `$this->request->data["questions"]`, but I keep getting a "index quiz/question not found" error. Is there a better way for me to be sending this data? Many many thanks to any help you can provide.

**Javascript**

```
var questions = [];
var currentQuizQuestion = 0;    

function saveNewQuestion()
{
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("inputQuestionForm"));
    questions[currentQuizQuestion] = formData;
    currentQuizQuestion++;
}

function saveQuiz()
{
    var quizData = new FormData(document.getElementById("inputQuizForm"));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "create",
        data:
        {
            quiz: quizData,
            questions: questions
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    });
}
```

**CakePHP**

```
public function create()
{
    if($this->request->is("post"))
    {
        $quiz = $this->request->data["quiz"];
        $questions = $this->request->data["questions"];
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `processData: false`? It may be causing undesirable results.

Comment: Not yet though that is because I was under the impression that removing the statement would cause jQuery to try and convert the formData objects into a query string, which would cause other errors. I may be wrong on that though

Comment: I believe you are correct on that. The other issue may be with your url, is `create` your PHP function?

Comment: Yeah I know that's working because I tested it out earlier on simpler commands and because that function is the one throwing the error. The weird thing is if I only pass one parameter through data ( `data: quizData`) then it works fine

Comment: what do you see if you do a debug($_POST); ? do it in the if statement in create.

Comment: Using debug($_POST) on the code above just gives me an empty array. If I modify the AJAX call to just send one parameter (per my previous comment) I instead get `['_method' => 'POST','qz_name' => 'adfasdfasd','qz_descrip' => 'asdfasdf','qz_tcat' => 'General','qz_private' => 'no']` which is what I expect. I'm confused as to why sending multiple parameters is causing issues.

Comment: You can't, everything has to be in *one* FormData object

Comment: Ahh - thanks @Musa, didn't realize that was a limitation. The workaround I came up with was to just make separate AJAX calls for each data parameter. Seems to work. Thanks for the help everyone.